# How can I verify the enum elements and eventually generate an error?

Tags: c, error-handling, enums

I'd like to decleare 2 enums and verify if the quantity of elements are equals. If not, I'd like to genereate an error. I tried with #if directive but enums are calculated after directives.

```
    typedef enum {
        A0,
        A1,
        A2,
        A3,
        A_ELEM_NR
    } DtbaseA;

    typedef enum {
        X0,
        X1,
        X2,
        B0,
        B1,
        B2,
        B3,
        B_ELEM_NR
    } DtbaseB;

    #if ((B_ELEM_NR - B0) != A_ELEM_NR)
        #errore ELEMENTS NOT EQUAL
    #endif
```

Comment: You could assert at compile time using static assert (if available) or make your own static assert.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the preprocessor runs in a step before the actual parsing of the code happens. You could see it as it runs separately from the actual compiler.

That means the preprocessor doesn't know anything about symbols other than the ones defined by the preprocessor itself (macros, function-like macro arguments).

It's impossible to use any kind of other symbols, like enumeration symbolic constants, in the preprocessor.

If your compiler supports C11 you could use [`_Static_assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Static_assert) for a compile-time check by the compiler itself, which have access to all the (non-preprocessor) symbols. If your compiler doesn't support `_Static_assert` there are ways around that as well, if you search a little (a common way is to use the condition as an array size, if the condition is false the size would be zero which is invalid).